# Servlet 3.0 tiles definition in jar META-INF resources

Tags: struts2, jboss, jboss7.x, tiles, servlet-3.0

I am using the new Servlet 3.0 approach of packaging web resources (such as Javascript, CSS, and JSPs) in JAR files. The approach says that everything under JARROOT/src/META-INF/resources will get mounted to the WAR root when the application starts. All works file for CSS and Javascript but not so much for Struts tiles.

This is the structure I have in the JAR:

```
base.jar
|--src/
|----META-INF/
|------base.tld
|------resources/
|--------base/
|----------css/
|----------js/
|----------baseTiles.xml
```

In my application (WAR) web.xml I got this for the tiles:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml,/base/baseTiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When I start my application I do not get any errors about the baseTiles.xml so I assume it would the tiles files. However, trying to reference a tile from a JSP (using the `<tiles:insertAttribute>` tag) fails with

```
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'base.nav' not found.
```

What do you think the is?

Summary and other info:

- Using JBoss eap 6.1 Alpha
- Using Struts 2.1.4
- The base JAR is included with the WAR in the lib directory
- The base JAR contain all the files mentioned above (including baseTiles.xml)

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! Must point to the right Schema in your web.xml...

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
```

Now everything works automagically !!

Answer (score 0):

It is the right schema definition for 3.1 servlet specification:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
```